# Split string in Thymeleaf on sequential characters

Tags: javascript, thymeleaf

I'm using Thymeleaf to split a string on multiple sequential characters but the results I'm seeing aren't what I expect. This is some old code and I don't want to have to rewrite it (doesn't everyone say that?).
I dumped the Java String and it looks something like this:

```
string 1:-string : 2:-string -3:-string 4
```

My code then splits it using

```
th:with="strarray=${#strings.arraySplit(inputString, ':-')}"
```

What I want is a strarray with 4 elements [string 1,string : 2,string -3,string -4] but the split appears to split the string on either the colon or hyphen, not :- as sequential characters. So my array ends up as [string 1, string , : ,string ,3,string 4]. The Thymeleaf documentation give no help so I'm asking here.

Answer (score 1):

I would say ideally, you should do the split in Java, and pass an array to Thymeleaf. But it sounds as if you would prefer to minimize changes. So you can use something like the following:

```
th:with="strarray=${#strings.arraySplit(#strings.replace(inputString, ':-', '~'), '~')}"
```

This replaces each `:-` with one symbol - in this case `~` - and then proceeds to split on that single symbol.

This results in the following 4 items in your `${strarray}`:

```
string 1
string : 2
string -3
string 4
```

Of course the risk here is that you have to choose a character which is guaranteed to not appear in the original string.

Comment: This works for me. I even think using the tilde is safe. Thanks for the suggestion.